# How to map function returning array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In example 1. I can map the function by passing it as prop to child component, however, what if i don't want to pass the function as a prop to a child component, how can i map the function in the main component itself as shown in example 2.

EXAMPLE 1.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
     <div>
       <Foo data={data()} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return (
      <div>
        {this.props.data.map(item => {
          return (
             <div>{item.id} {item.name}</div>
           )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


function data() {
  return (
   [
     {id: 1, name: "Jack"},
     {id: 2, name: "Mark"},
     {id: 3, name: "Mike"},
     {id: 4, name: "Russell"}
   ]
  )
}
```

EXAMPLE 2.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
     <div>
       {this.data().map(() => {
          //I know this is not correct so what is the right way.
        })}           
      </div>
    )
  }
}


function data() {
  return (
   [
     {id: 1, name: "Jack"},
     {id: 2, name: "Mark"},
     {id: 3, name: "Mike"},
     {id: 4, name: "Russell"}
   ]
  )
}
```

Comment: Remove `this.` if `data` is just a function in scope without any context as exemplified in your question.

Comment: `{data().map`...? Not sure why you’re using global.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is what you are looking for.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
     <div>
       {data().map(item => {
           return (
              <div>{item.id} {item.name} </div>
           )
       })}           
      </div>
    )
  }
}


function data() {
  return (
   [
     {id: 1, name: "Jack"},
     {id: 2, name: "Mark"},
     {id: 3, name: "Mike"},
     {id: 4, name: "Russell"}
   ]
  )
}
```